# Matplotlib freezes/crashes when running this exercise

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to run an exercise from Python Crash Course in which I'm generating a Random Walk with an input in a loop that asks whether or not to generate a new Random Walk when I close out of the chart. Every time I close out of the screen with the chart however, matplotlib freezes and subsequently crashes/stops responding. I'm wondering why this is happening. Thank you.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

from random_walk import RandomWalk 

# make a random walk


rw = RandomWalk()
rw.fill_walk()

plt.style.use('classic')

#plot the points in the walk
while True:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, s=15)
    plt.show()

    keep_running = input("Make another walk? (y/n): ")
    if keep_running == 'n':
        break
```

Comment: If it crashes, you have successfully completed the crash course ;)

Comment: Did you enter `n` before closing the window? Or after closing the window?

Comment: i'm not even able to enter anything, since as soon as i close out of the window i get a spinning beach ball (i'm on OSX)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are never making a new random walk if you quit with 'y'. Instead it restarts the infinite loop with the same data as before, so you are overwritting data on the same graph. Try including the random Walk creating inside your while loop. Also try calling plt.close() after keep_running = ....

Comment: that does make sense, thank you. however when i close out of the window, Python/matplotlib just freezes and stops responding

Comment: did you try calling plt.close() or did you close the window manually.

Comment: import sys
sys.exit() is a better alternative to exit a python script than breaking a while loop